# why is Map() not rendering itemlist, but the items can be rendered individually in reactjs??

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, rendering, javascript-objects

So...I stumbled upon a bump in the road for a an app with(reactjs,redux,firebase/firestore)

The thing is that i fetch data from firestore and save it inside the ourPosts variable with useState([]) initialization. The problem is that when i display each post manually with ourPosts[x] syntax, the post display(renders), but when i itterate into the ourPosts[] array with array.map() nothings renders on the screen and no errors are given.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Avatar } from '@mui/material';
import "./Chats.css";
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import ChatBubbleIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChatBubble';
import { collection,  onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from './firebase';
import Chat from "./Chat"
function Chats() {
    const [ourPosts, setPosts] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        const colRef = collection(db,"posts"); 
        const q = query(colRef, orderBy("timestamp", "desc"));
        const posts = []
        onSnapshot(q, (snapshot)=>{
               
               snapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=> {
               posts.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id});
               
            }) 
        })
       setPosts(posts);

        
        console.log(posts)

    },[])
  return (
    <div className="chats">
        <div className="chats__header">
            <Avatar className='chats__avatar' src=""/>
            <div className="chats__search">
                <SearchIcon/>
                <input type="text" placeholder='Friend' />
            </div>
            <ChatBubbleIcon className='chats__chatIcon'/>
        </div>

        <div className="chats__posts">
            
            { 
                ourPosts?.map((post) => {
                    return (<Chat
                     key={post.id}
                     ourPost={post}
                
                     
                    />)
                

                    })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chats
```

And the child component looks like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { Avatar } from '@mui/material'
import "./Chat.css"
function Chat({ourPost}) {
    return (
        <div className='chat'>
           <Avatar className='chat__avatar' />
           <div className="chat__info">
               <h4>{ourPost.username}</h4>
               <p>Tap to view - {new Date(ourPost.timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chat;
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(posts)` and `console.log(ourPosts)` ?

Comment: the console.log(posts) is returning an array with objects of single posts fetched from firebase with onSnapshot, console.log(ourPosts) return the array saved in the state as it should. how so?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the return in the mapping should not be there.
Check out the [array mapping api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information.

But it should be fine once you change it to

```
ourPosts?.map((post) => 
  <Chat
     key={post.id}
     ourPost={post}
  />
)
```

Comment: this sisnt change it unfortunately, but the onload() method on window object made it work, seems like it was useeffect